# How do you use lazy in the user and password properties of a resource

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I'm trying to use a variable that is created at runtime for the user and password properties of a execute resource.  Ultimately I'm just trying to create a directory as a specific user.

The command works if I comment out the user and password properties.  It will create a folder with the usernmae variable.  Whenever I add back the user and password properties I get the no method error.  I can echo the variables and they are both correct so i'm assuming it's my syntax?

```
 execute "mkdir" do
    command lazy { "mkdir c:\\temp\\#{node.run_state['cred1']['UserName']}" }
    user lazy { "#{node.run_state['cred1']['UserName']}" }
    password lazy { "#{node.run_state['cred1']['Content']}" }
 end

FATAL: NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

Comment: does it work for you when you change `node.run_state` with `node.default`?

Comment: No, I get an invalid username/password error.  This makes sense since variables get defined during runtime.  I'm using the CyberArk cookbook in my recipe:  https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/cyberark The sample file resource provided on the supermarket site works for me.  I only have issues when I try using the variable in the user/password properties.

Comment: This appears to be a bug.  The user and password properties in execute and powershell_script (more than likely all resources that accept these properties but I haven't tested others) resources do not honor the lazy evaluation and end it compiling a node.run_state variable which is causing my NoMethodError/compile error.  I've been able to call the node.run_state variable in other properties such as command, owner, code, and content in various resources.

Comment: Just an FYI to anyone that comes across this.  The lazy operator does not work for the user / password properties as there is a script called eager that compile those properties.  I have to create a custom resource since they are inherently lazy.